# jquery is() to match all elements, not any

Tags: jquery

If I have this HTML:

```
<input type="button" />
<input type="button" />
<input class="btn" type="button" />
<div class="btn"></div>
<div class="btn"></div>
```

I have 3 buttons in a jQuery object.. say `var buttons = $(':button');`.

Then I have another object that has a different 3 set of elements, ONE of them, being the same: `var nextButtons = $('.btn');`

Is there a jQuery way of checking if **all** the elements are the same? `is()` seems to return true if **any** of the elements match.

**EDIT:**

I mean a comparison in the exact same way that `is()` works. I'd guess, this function would call `is()` for each element in the first set, for each of the second set.

Comment: @RabNawaz Same element type i guess.

Comment: So you'd want to know that all elements in each set were both `type="button"` and of `class="btn"`?

Comment: Yes, there is, where do you want to check the type of the elements?

Comment: In the same way that `is()` works. I wouldn't expect a library to do a different method of comparison depending on whether you want to compare all or any elements from the matched sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing built-in, but it's really easy to do:

```
$.fn.all = function(selector) {
    return this.filter(selector).length == this.length;
}
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/CuDDZ/)**.

Comment: Fantastic. The `selector` parameter was misleading, this indeed works with jQuery objects, DOM elements, selectors and functions, just like the `is()` function does. Thanks!

Comment: @ConnellWatkins: Sure, since it passes the parameter directly to `filter`. For the name I used the same as the documentation for `is` and `filter`. ;-)

Comment: Yup, as soon as I realised it worked for the lot, I asked myself; "what do jQuery name their parameters then?" and found out for myself :) Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can try `.filter()`

```
var buttons= $(".btn").filter(function(i){
                   return $(this).is("input[type='button']");
              });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/qHqAH/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (buttons.length === nextButtons.length && buttons.filter(nextButtons).length) {
     console.log("Same");
}
```